# Filter some entered chat templates using meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor

I created a quick little demo of a chat using Meteor looks like this: [image: My quick little bad looking demo]

In the section where I have "Hi" I would like to now filter by the term entered into there. So in this case "Hi" should show the message "Hi there". However I'm not certain how to force the template to change the HTML. I'm using a helper to get the collection returned:

```
Template.body.helpers({"allmessages": function(){
        return mMessages.find({text : {$regex : ".*"+ mSearchQuery + ".*"}});
      }})
```

I'm familiar with observable design pattern, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to tell the template that its dependency has changed. Thanks for any help!

HTML:

```
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>hello</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="row base-container">
    <div class="col s12 indigo lighten-3 chat-container row">
        {{#each allmessages}}
            {{>templatemessage}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>

    <form class="col s12 blue lighten-3 row small-container">
        <textarea class="col s9 chat-input"></textarea>
        <div class="col s2 offset-s1 row">
            <button class="col s12 btn waves-effect waves-light send-button" type="submit" name="action"><span class="submit-text">Submit</span>
                <i class="material-icons">send</i>
            </button>

            <input type="text" class="search-query col s10"/>
            <i class="material-icons s2 col">search</i>

        </div>

    </form>
</div>



</body>

<template name="templatemessage">
    <div class="row message-container col s12">
        <div class="user-name col s3"></div>
        <div class="user-message col s9">{{text}}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Javascript=

```
mMessages = new Meteor.Collection("messages");
mUsers = new Meteor.Collection("users");

var mSearchQuery = "";

var mCurrentUser = null;

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  $(function () {
    $(".search-query").enterKey(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      mSearchQuery = $(this).val();
      Template.body.registerhe
      return false;
    })
  });

  $.fn.enterKey = function (fnc, mod) {
    return this.each(function () {
      $(this).keypress(function (ev) {
        var keycode = (ev.keyCode ? ev.keyCode : ev.which);
        if ((keycode == '13' || keycode == '10') && (!mod || ev[mod + 'Key'])) {
          fnc.call(this, ev);
        }
      })
    })
  }

  Template.body.events({
    "click .send-button" : function(event){
      var test = $("textarea.chat-input");
      mMessages.insert({"user" : mCurrentUser, "text" : test.val()})
      test.val('');
      return false;
    }
  })

  Template.body.helpers({"allmessages": function(){
    return mMessages.find({text : {$regex : ".*"+ mSearchQuery + ".*"}});
  }})
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Comment: And no need for all the m's before collection names and variables...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sort of confused what you want to do, but to get the rerender magic you need to use reactive variables. Use either session or reactive var.

Template helpers are reactive contexts, but if you're not in one, look at autorun in the docs.